# How to remove "Super Admin" from All Users for those that are not a "Super Admin"?

Tags: admin, users, user-roles, user-access

I would like to remove the filter at the top that says "Super Admin" for users that are not a "Super Admin". How do I go about doing this?

This screenshot shows what I am talking about: 
[image]

Comment: Where does this appears to you??? . . . . `/wp-admin/network/users.php` , `/wp-admin/users.php` ?

Comment: @brasofilo - this appears in WP-Admin > Users > All Users menu

Comment: Are you using a Custom Roles plugin?

Comment: @brasofilo - yes, I am using User Role Editor.

Comment: Há! Please provide as much details as you can in your Questions, otherwise it's almost a guessing game... *Super Admin* is a role name in WordPress Multisite, hence my first comment. . . . I see that you already have 12 questions, but still haven't earned the [Analytical badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/77/analytical)...

Comment: @brasofilo - sorry!

Comment: No problem, mate. You can always edit/update your Question after exchanging info through Comments or Answers. If no answer comes up, I'll take a look tomorrow, cheers!

Comment: If I remember correctly only super admins will even see this menu, this menu is hidden for any other level. You can test this by login-in with a useraccount who has no super admin privileges and see what he sees.

Answer (score 2):

This list of filters at the top of admin screens are called *Views*.  You can manage views using the `views_{$this->screen->id}` filter.  Where you'd replace `{$this->screen->id}` with the name of the screen you'd like to manage.

In order to filter the `Users` screen, you can try the following:

```
// filter the 'users' views
add_filter( "views_users", "wse57231_filter_user_views");

function wse57231_filter_user_views($views){
  // This assumes the key for the role is 'super_admin'
  // Is the current user not a "super_admin"?

  if( !current_user_can('super_admin')){
    // Remove the super_admin view from the list of views
    unset($views['super_admin']);
  }

  return $views;
}
```

References:
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/views_this-screen-id/
 * http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

*Note: Based on the comments, it sounds like `Super Admin` is a custom role you've created.  This is partially confusing because Super Admin is also the name of a special role when using WordPress Multisite.*

Comment: Although it works, I've read that it's better not to use current_user_can() as function to check a users' role. Instead it's better to use the "roles" property of the WP_User object.
A couple of articles I found on this (both in spanish):
1) https://cybmeta.com/por-favor-deja-de-utilizar-current_user_can-para-comprobar-roles-de-usuario
2) https://cybmeta.com/como-comprobar-el-rol-de-un-usuario